# MateNu Python Installation help

Tags: python, windows-xp, mate, ubuntu-mate

I really want some info on what version of Python to install for MateNu, and how to install all the add-ons quickly. Here is the list from the readme itself:

```
python, python-xdg, python-cairo, python-gtk2, python, python-xdg, python-cairo, python-gtk2, python-imaging, python-wnck, python-keybinder, python-numpy, python-xlib, libxml2, python-libxml2
```

NEW: There, success on Python! Now how do I run `install.sh` on MATE without a text editor?

Comment: I changed it to be more specific. :)

Comment: OK thats alot better, please try to be clear an concise when asking:)

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask a new question, but as this is very simple I will answer it in this comment `./path/to/your/file.sh` dont forget the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Python is already installed in Ubuntu (2.7 & 3), so you don't need to install these packages.

You can get a deb file and install it by simply running these commands from a terminal

```
wget https://launchpad.net/matenu/1.0/unstable/+download/matenu_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/matenu_1.0-1_all.deb
```

If you face dependency issues use `gdebi` to auto resolve them

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi ~/matenu_1.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: That should do it I think, but any issues please do comment.

Comment: Didn't work. This message showed: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of matenu:
 matenu depends on python-rsvg; however:
  Package python-rsvg is not installed.
 matenu depends on alacarte; however:
  Package alacarte is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package matenu (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matenu` I presume Python isn't fully installed?

Comment: Sorry my bad I did not test, new way is tested by me on Xubuntu and works. If it works for you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others find the correct answer :)

Comment: I think I sorta did it? uh...

Comment: If it worked the last two lines of output should be `Unpacking matenu (1.0-1) ...
Setting up matenu (1.0-1) ...`